# VB Listview show items vertical

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a simple form with 2 labels, 2 textboxes, 1 button and 1 listview.
In the textboxes I want to input the names and ages of people.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Col1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim Col2 As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
    lvi.Text = Col1
    lvi.SubItems.Add(Col2)
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
End Sub
End Class
```

I got this code working, but when I input more than 1 name in textbox1 and more than 1 age in textbox2 the output in listview will be horizontal. And I want it to be vertical. Textboxes are multiline

Comment: Add each item (line element) as a new LVI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the value supplied from textbox1 and textbox2 using the CRLF.  Aggregate each row from textbox1 and textbox2 to create each ListViewItem, looping for each row.

```
Dim tb1 As String() = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbCrlf)
Dim tb2 As String() = Split(TextBox2.Text, vbCrlf)
For i = 0 To tb1.Length - 1
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
    lvi.Text = tb1(i)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(tb2(i))
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Tried your code but it will give the same results. Items will be added horizontally.

Comment: Also ... make sure you have columns added to the list view.  This is fully working on my side.